# Number of core feelings?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion, brain, emotional-intelligence

In [Emotional Intelligence 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0974320625) it is stated:

> We have so many words to describe the feelings that surface in life,
>   yet all emotions are derivations of five core feelings: happiness,
>   sadness, anger, fear, and shame.

This chart is used to categorize different feelings under these core emotions.

[image]

Interesting that there are 4 negative and only 1 positive core feeling. Also to note there is 'Heartbroken' in the sad category. However, is there is no 'love' feeling to match 'Heartbroken'.

Hence, the main question: Does the current psychology understanding back up this sort of categorization? And is 'love' really non-existent as a discrete feeling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/17265/7001.  Another possibility is https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/8510/what-is-the-most-comprehensive-system-of-describing-human-emotions-or-states-of

Comment: Good question. But, in terms of, "is there is no 'love' feeling to match 'Heartbroken'", consider that being in love and heartbroken go hand in hand. They are not opposites.

Comment: Those possible duplicates are definitely relevant! Perhaps focus this question specifically on the last question only, the one about love. In that case, I don't think it is a dupe.